# How to use postgres function result as a separate column in DELETE query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have to delete rows in a table based on multiple comparisons with a really long function application on one of the columns. To go a bit into details, i'm decoding from base64, doing a substring, transforming to `json`, taking a specific field, then transforming that to `inet`.

I'm using those ips to compare with other ips / masks in my `WHERE` clause.

The problem i have is that obtaining the actual result is a pretty long string, and if i end up saying `ip < foo(bar(baz(quux))) OR ip2 < foo(bar(baz(quux)))` then that value for comparison will end up being calculated multiple times too.

I'm looking for a way to precompute that value, assign it a meaningful name, then use that name in my `WHERE` clause.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select . . .
from t cross join lateral
     (values (foo(bar(baz(quux))) ) v(decoded_value)
where ip < v.decoded_vaue or ip2 < v.decoded_value;
```

In Postgres, a `delete` is a little trickier.  Assuming you have a primary key:

```
delete t
using t t2 cross join lateral
     (values (foo(bar(baz(t2.quux))) ) v(decoded_value)
where t2.primary_key = t.primary_key and
      (t2.ip < v.decoded_vaue or t2.ip2 < v.decoded_value);
```

Comment: I'm doing a `DELETE`, not a select, so would using a join not actually have me end up with a different table / view ?

Comment: That second one will do it i think. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the usage of a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html)?

For example, let's say that we have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  some_data INTEGER
);
```

Let's say that we want to delete all of the rows in which the result of the expression

> some_data % 10

is (>=1 and <=4) or (>=6 and <=8).

In this case the modulo operation replaces your `foo(bar(baz(column_name)))` call with the modulo operation.

The simple approach would be to write the following query:

```
DELETE FROM test_table
WHERE
  (MOD(some_data, 10) >= 1 AND MOD(some_data, 10) <= 4)
  OR
  (MOD(some_data, 10) >=6 AND MOD(some_data, 10) <= 8);
```

As you said, this will recalculate the same thing multiple times. In order to do the calculation only once, we can create a `CTE` and use the result in the delete query.

```
WITH precalculated_table AS (
  SELECT *, mod(some_data, 10) as mod_10_result FROM test_table
)
DELETE FROM test_table WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id from precalculated_table
  where
    (mod_10_result >= 1 and mod_10_result <= 4)
    OR
    (mod_10_result >= 6 AND mod_10_result <= 8)
);
```

This way, we do the calculation only once and then we use the precaculated column in the `WHERE` part of the `DELETE` query.